# Setting maximum worker threads in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new to Python/Django, and haven't found anything online on whether I can set the maximum number of worker threads in Django. For example, I want Django to serve only 10 requests maximum concurrently. If there are more than 10, it will have to wait in a queue (ideally I can set the max number of requests in this queue too?)

I come from a Ruby background, and know that in Unicorn, you can set the max number of worker_processes. Is there something similar in Django? I don't want a scenario where my Django app is processing thousands of requests at the same time.

Comment: You can do the same in Gunicorn, or whatever WSGI server you choose. Django itself, like Rails, doesn't control the number of threads.

Comment: Adding to @knbk 's answer: if you let us know which WSGI you are using, we might be able to give you more accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

from here: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/configure.html

```
import multiprocessing

bind = "127.0.0.1:8000"
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
```

In your case set workers = 10